# What is the .yarn/berry/cache folder for when using Yarn 3?

Tags: caching, yarnpkg, yarn-v3

I'm building a Docker image using Yarn 3 and I've noticed that on that image it creates two cache folders:

```
.yarn/cache
.yarn/berry/cache
```

Both appears to contain the same content (the .zip package files).

The first one, `.yarn/cache`, makes sense and is the same as what I have on my local machine, but the second, `.yarn/berry/cache`, doesn't. "Berry" appears to be the codename of Yarn 2+ but I can't find any information about why it would create such a duplicate directory.

Any idea what it's about?